# using busctl as non-root user

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, d-bus

I'm trying to start/stop/determine the status of a user systemd service file from within a program, not running as root, using the systemd sd-bus API.

Let's stay with the example of determining the status. I tested that stuff on the command line. I made some progress when preparing the environment with:

```
$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
```

and

```
$ export $(dbus-launch)
```

which I found in different sources when searching on the web. When calling with that certain user:

```
$ busctl --user --verbose get-property \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
   /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/myservice \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit ActiveState
```

the result:

```
Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Where before it was something like "Permission denied". While running as root, without the user flag, gives me the desired output.

Anyone have any hints what I might be missing?